# Cannot use getAccessTokenAsync on Mobile

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I created an Office.js add-in that works fine on OWA and Outlook desktop app. But, on the Outlook app for iOS and Android, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read proerties of undefined (reading 'getAccessTokenAsync')
```

Can I not use the function Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync if I plan on using the add-in on mobile? If it is allowed, then what can I do to get around this error? I've also tried using Promise.resolve(OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()), but got this error -

```
ReferenceError: OfficeRuntime is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAccessTokenAsync` is a part of IdentityAPI 1.3 and is not available for Outlook Mobile yet. You can see the list of supported API sets on Outlook for different platforms [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets).

Comment: Any update when this will be available?. Also can you provide your upcoming release items or backlog items list if you maintain them publicly.